# How to make dataframes from lists by factors in R

Tags: r, list, split

I have a list data

```
test1 <- list( c(ID='a',VALUE='va1'), 
               c(ID='a',VALUE='va2'),
               c(ID='b',VALUE='vb1'),
               c(ID='c',VALUE='vc1'), 
               c(ID='c',VALUE='vc2'),
               c(ID='c',VALUE='vc3'))
```

And, I would like to split and merge to 3 dataframes with ID names,

please let me know how to store each data into new dataframe which has a name with thier ID.

```
|  ID  |    VALUE    |
|  a   |   va1 va2   | 

|  ID  |    VALUE    |    
|  b   |     vb2     | 

|  ID  |    VALUE    |
|  c   | vc1 vc2 vc3 |
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `d1 <-  as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, test1)); split(d1, d1$VALUE)`

Comment: @akrun this gives, "Error in d1$VALUE : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors" for me...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It was bound, but I can't split with split(d1, d1$ID).

Comment: @akrun I think `split(d1, d1$ID)` is what's needed

Comment: @Jaap Yes, I typed the wrong variable

Answer (score 3):

In `base R` we can aggregate `VALUE` after binding the list together, then split.

```
a <- aggregate(VALUE ~ ., do.call(rbind, test1), toString)
split(a, a$ID)
# $a
#   ID    VALUE
# 1  a va1, va2
# 
# $b
#   ID VALUE
# 2  b   vb1
# 
# $c
#   ID         VALUE
# 3  c vc1, vc2, vc3
```

To access each data frame, you can use:

```
s <- split(a, a$ID)
s$a
#  ID    VALUE
#1  a va1, va2

#or
s[[1]]
#  ID    VALUE
#1  a va1, va2
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works but, if you don't mind please let me know how to store each data into new dataframe which has a name with thier ID. Thanks!

Comment: @liveinfootball You should add this request to your original question.

Comment: Instead of making new objects in the global environment, you can access all of data frames from the list like `s <- split(a, a$ID); s$a` or by number with `s[[2]]`.

Comment: And my real data has more than 40,000 rows which has about 500characters, so it did not work when I use aggregate().

Comment: I just tested successfully on 50,000 rows with 250,000 characters

Comment: > a <- aggregate(Brand ~ ., do.call(rbind, carDF), toString)
Error: protect(): protection stack overflow This is what I have when I excute

Comment: This is data that I use https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B97ow4h4jwHceFBoOURzTTBEc2s

Comment: That is R's documented behavior. You can expand the memory allocation for big data sets by starting R from the command line. See [here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Memory.html) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32187410/error-protect-protection-stack-overflow-while-feature-extraction).

Comment: You shouldn't try to save so many values into the same vector position. You are creating a 250k+ single character string.